# VIM: how to get current window size, so that I can set NEEDTree to 1/3 window size?

Tags: vim, resize, window, size

I wish when I bring out NEEDTree or TagBar, the window size is always 1/3 of my original vim window size, no matter how big my vim window is, it's calculated automatically.

How to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

vim has built-in function `winwidth({nr})` to get window width. If you pass a `zero` as win number, it will return your the width of current window.

To change the window size of NerdTree, you have to set the variable: `NERDTreeWinSize`

Comment: I typed ":winwidth(0)" in vim command mode, but it says: E492: Not an editor command: winwidth(0).

Comment: @Troskyvs, it is a built-in **function**! not command. try `:echo winwidth(0)`

Comment: If someone ends up here and wants an equivalent for neovim, it is `vim.api.nvim_win_get_width({nr})`